# How to select from a table and up to two other items

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have three tables (don't ask why it was set up this way, it just was, this is a simplification but gets at the problem):

```
Table: players
id
username
weapon_id
shield_id

Table: items
id
name
stats (either attack or defend stats number)
item_type_id

Table: item_types
id
is_weapon (true if weapon, false if shield)
is_rare (true/false boolean)
```

Each player has either no items, 1 item, or 2 items. (Either a weapon, a shield, both, or neither, in which case the weapon_id and shield_id would be null)

I want to run a select query that gets:

```
Results of my query

id (of player)
username
weapon_id
weapon_name
weapon_stats
weapon_is_rare
shield_id
shield_name
shield_stats
shield_is_rare
```

In the case where shield_id is null, for example, the values in the result should just be null.

What's a good SQL query to get this sort of result from this setup?

Comment: what have you tried? I hope someone doesn't just give you the answer. you should post your attempts. heres a hint you want to run a select statement and left join the tables so that you can get the values if they are there or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` with the `items` and `item_types` table separately for the weapon and shield. Use table aliases to distinguish which join you're referencing.

```
SELECT 
  p.id
 ,p.username
 ,p.weapon_id
 ,w.name     AS weapon_name
 ,w.stats    AS weapon_stats
 ,wt.is_rare  AS weapon_is_rare
 ,p.shield_id
 ,s.name     AS shield_name
 ,s.stats    AS shield_stats
 ,st.is_rare  AS shield_is_rare
FROM players AS p
LEFT JOIN items AS w ON w.id = p.weapon_id
LEFT JOIN item_types AS wt ON wt.id = w.item_type_id
LEFT JOIN items AS s ON s.id = p.shield_id
LEFT JOIN item_types AS st ON st.id = s.item_type_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with the `players` table as the main table you are querying. As others have said, you are going to want to `LEFT JOIN` the other tables to the `players` table on the foreign keys that match.

If you aren't sure which join type to use, look here: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php

That page is for Oracle DB, but the same concept applies to all flavors of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  p.id
 ,p.username
 ,p.weapon_id
 ,i1.name     AS weapon_name
 ,i1.stats    AS weapon_stats
 ,i1.is_rare  AS weapon_is_rare
 ,p.shield_id
 ,i2.name     AS shield_name
 ,i2.stats    AS shield_stats
 ,i2.is_rare  AS shield_is_rare
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.id, i.name, i.stats, it.is_rare
           FROM items i 
           JOIN item_types it 
             ON i.item_type_id = it.id) AS i1
  ON p.weapon_id = i1.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.id, i.name, i.stats, it.is_rare
           FROM items i 
           JOIN item_types it 
             ON i.item_type_id = it.id) AS i2
  ON p.shield_id = i2.id;
```